# Msg 4832 Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file

Tags: csv, sql-server-express, bulk-load

I am trying to bulk load a `.csv` file into SQL Server 2014 Express. Digging through StackOverflow and googling in general, everyone seems to agree that it is an issue of to few columns in the `.csv` file. Unfortunately none of the answers are working for me. So I can only assume that I am doing something wrong, because even my simple 2 column table I have created to test with does not work.

My test table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempC1C2]
(
    [c1] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [c2] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My test data:

```
First,Last
```

My load script:

```
Bulk Insert TempC1C2 From
'C:\test.csv'
With(datafiletype='native', FieldTerminator =',', rowterminator='\r\n', errorfile='C:\error.log')
```

Error.log output:

```
First,Last
Fi
```

error.log.Error.txt

```
Row 1 File Offset 0 ErrorFile Offset 0 - HRESULT 0x80004005
```

Comment: I have updated the rowterminator='\n' to '\r\n' as marc_s suggested. It is still not working for me so I have updated my post with the error log results.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `rowterminator` is wrong - this using `\r\n`:

```
BULK INSERT TempC1C2 
FROM 'C:\test.csv'
WITH (datafiletype='native', 
      fieldTerminator =',', 
      rowterminator='\r\n', 
      errorfile='C:\error.log')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, marc_s, but this is not working for me. I tried simply hitting enter to move to the next line and I have also tried using Notepad++ to insert the '\r\n' via replacing a '~' that I have added to the end of the row. I will update my original post with the outputs of the error logs. It might help more.